# Trying to get a specific text/value from a xml file on a c# Console app

Tags: c#, xml

Hello currently i got my app to display the information i wanted but now i need to get it to search so to say on a if statement cause there is one line on the xml file that as a error that i need to be pointed out on the console.If anyone knows a question that as a solution on this topic please put it on the comments it would help me out a lot.

```
        using System;
        using System.Xml;
        using System.IO;
        namespace XmlReaderConsoleAPP
       {
        class Program
       {
        static void Main()
        {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {

            xml.Load("c:\\SaintGobain_Pam_20210118 .xml");
        }
         catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Erro: {0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
       
        XmlNodeList xnLista = xml.SelectNodes(@"//Pages/Page");
        Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista.Count} nodes");
        int i = 0;
       
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista)
        {

           
            Console.WriteLine($"{++i} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["ImportFileName"].Value}");
        }

        XmlNodeList xnLista2 = xml.SelectNodes(@"//IndexFields/IndexField");
        Console.WriteLine($"Selected {xnLista2.Count} nodes");

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnLista2)
        {

           
            Console.WriteLine($"{++i} {xn.Name}: {xn.Attributes["Value"].Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

}

So this is my code for the c# app

and this is my code on the xml file

```
<ImportSession>
<Batches>
<Batch Name="MSG_SaintGobainPam_20210118" Description="SaintGobain_20210118" 
  BatchClassName="SAINTGOBAIN - Faturas Notas" Processed="1">
  <BatchFields>
    <BatchField Name="CAPALOTE" Value="0" />
    <BatchField Name="NCONTENTOR" Value="0" />
  </BatchFields>
  <Documents>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047804" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047804.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047842" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047842.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047843" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047843.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047849" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047849.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047853" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047853.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047854" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047854.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047855" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047855.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047860" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047860.pdf" ErrorCode="20" ErrorMessage="Illegal file format (\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047860.pdf)" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
    <Document FormTypeName="DOC_SaintGobain_Faturas_Notas">
      <IndexFields>
        <IndexField Name="ETIQUETA" Value="ZE80047861" />
      </IndexFields>
      <Pages>
        <Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047861.pdf" />
      </Pages>
    </Document>
  </Documents>
</Batch>
```

And what i want to do is like being if there is a error it shows it and if not it just shows everything before the value i want it to find is this one

```
<Page ImportFileName="\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047860.pdf" ErrorCode="20" 
ErrorMessage="Illegal file format (\\umm\c$\acxmlaid\SaintGobain\20210118\ZE80047860.pdf)" />
```

Thank you all for the help and hope i can make this work with your help.
Tiago Silva

Comment: `xn.Attributes["ErrorMessage"]?.Value ?? string.Empty` will give you the empty string if xn does not have the attribute ErrorMessage and if it does, then it returns the ErrorMessage.

Comment: @Fildor my man you are a genius dam, thanks ill try it out

Comment: @Fildor is it possible to put it on a if statment like if there is a error message and else there isent one?

Comment: @Fildor by the way Fildor can you up this vote also or what can i do to fix this score im really trying my best to get back to making questions and contributting

Comment: @Fildor Check the answer and see if it qualifies has correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this question turned out easy at the end i just switched to objects(making my xml file turn into objects) and serializing them, next since i wanted to make a way for the program to find the error i just did this.

```
public class ImportSession
    {
        public Batch[] Batches { get; set; }
    }
    public class Batch
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string BatchClassName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool Processed { get; set; }
        public Document[] Documents { get; set; }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string FormTypeName { get; set; }
        public IndexField[] IndexFields { get; set; }
        public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
    }

    public class IndexField
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Page
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ImportFileName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool HasError => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage);
    }

}
```

As you can see my public bool HasError is catching the error and then

```
private static void ProcessFile(string filename, XmlSerializer serializer, string fName, string batchName, string description, string BatchCName)
    {
     
        Console.WriteLine("A processar xml: " + filename);
        bool temErro = false;
       
        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var session = (ImportSession)serializer.Deserialize(file);
     
            foreach (Batch batch in session.Batches)
            {
                fName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                BatchCName = batch.BatchClassName;
                batchName = batch.Name;
                description = batch.Description;
                foreach (Document doc in batch.Documents)
                {
                    foreach (Page page in doc.Pages)
                    {
            @            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch.Processed.ToString()))
                        {
                            if (page.HasError)
                            {
                               
                                string Import = page.ImportFileName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Página com erro:" + Import + fName);
                                temErro = true;                                
                                da.SP_Insert(filename,fName,BatchCName,batchName,description,1,Import,0, "");
```

With the line

```
if (page.HasError)
                            {
                               
                                string Import = page.ImportFileName;
                                Console.WriteLine("Página com erro:" + Import + fName);
                                temErro = true;
```

I end up writing that the page as error with its name(Import) and the variable temErro(HasError) is set to true, this line`if (page.HasError)` is thanks to objects since page is a object and inside it there is the HasError bool.
If anyone needs anymore explaining please tell me i´d be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

"is it possible to put it on a if statment like if there is a error message and else there isent one? " - sure:

```
string value = xn.Attributes["ErrorMessage"]?.Value; // null if no ErrorMessage
if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
{
    // Case of no error
}
else
{
    // Case of error
}
```

Or if you intend to show it *instead* of ImportFileName-Value:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{xn.Attributes["ErrorMessage"]?.Value ?? xn.Attributes["ImportFileName"]?.Value}");
```